# Big-oh for function of two variables

Tags: computer-science, asymptotics

Is it true that $O(M^3 + NM^2) \, = \, O(M^3 + N)$, where $M$ and $N$ are variables of the function?

Comment: Set $M=0$; then $M^3 + NM^2$ vanishes, but $M^3 + N$ does not.

Comment: Technically, setting M=0 doesn't quite work, since the bound only has to hold for all M,N sufficiently large.

Answer (score 6):

[Throughout this answer, I'm going to use set notation in order to be pedantic.]

It is true that $O(M^3+N)\subset O(M^3+NM^2)$, since for $M$ sufficiently large, $c(M^3+N)<c(M^3+NM^2)$. It's worth noting that for $M$ sufficiently close to $0$, $M^3+N>M^3+NM^2$.

For the reverse inclusion, consider $f(M,N)=M^3+NM^2$. Clearly $f\in O(M^3+NM^2)$. We now need to show that for all $c$ and arbitrarily large $M,N$ that $f(M,N)>c(M^3+N)$. We can do this by setting $M=\log N$. We then have $f(\log N,N)=\log^3 N + N\log^2 N$, which is clearly larger than $c(\log^3 N + N)$ for all sufficiently large $N$. So $f(M,N)\not\in O(M^3+N)$.